# bulk update jenkins Job Restrictions Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

i have a lot of jobs and need to make the same change of the Job Restrictions Plugin to all of them, i have tried with groovy but couldn't find the jobs that contain this plugin.
another issue that i can't extract the used plugins in a specific job with groovy and i wonder if there is any methods for this.